# group by and picking up first value in spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing group by action in spark sql.In that some rows contain same value with different ID.In that case I want to select first row.

This is my code.

```
    val highvalueresult = highvalue.select($"tagShortID", $"Timestamp", $"ListenerShortID", $"rootOrgID", $"subOrgID",  $"RSSI_Weight_avg")
                          .groupBy("tagShortID", "Timestamp").agg(max($"RSSI_Weight_avg")
                          .alias("RSSI_Weight_avg"))

        val t2 = averageDF.join(highvalueresult, Seq("tagShortID", "Timestamp", "RSSI_Weight_avg"))
```

And this is my result.

```
tag,timestamp,rssi,listner,rootorg,suborg
2,1496745906,0.7,3878,4,3
4,1496745907,0.6,362,4,3
4,1496745907,0.6,718,4,3
4,1496745907,0.6,1901,4,3
```

In the above result for the time stamp 1496745907 same rssi values for three listner.In this case I want to select the first row.

Comment: What you are looking for is exactly in that link

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the windowing functions support that spark sql context has
Assuming you dataframe is:

```
+---+----------+----+-------+-------+------+
|tag| timestamp|rssi|listner|rootorg|suborg|
+---+----------+----+-------+-------+------+
|  2|1496745906| 0.7|   3878|      4|     3|
|  4|1496745907| 0.6|    362|      4|     3|
|  4|1496745907| 0.6|    718|      4|     3|
|  4|1496745907| 0.6|   1901|      4|     3|
+---+----------+----+-------+-------+------+
```

Define a window function as(you can partition by/order by your columns):

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("timestamp", "rssi").orderBy("timestamp")
```

Apply the window function:

```
res1.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(window))
+---+----------+----+-------+-------+------+----+
|tag| timestamp|rssi|listner|rootorg|suborg|rank|
+---+----------+----+-------+-------+------+----+
|  4|1496745907| 0.6|    362|      4|     3|   1|
|  4|1496745907| 0.6|    718|      4|     3|   2|
|  4|1496745907| 0.6|   1901|      4|     3|   3|
|  2|1496745906| 0.7|   3878|      4|     3|   1|
+---+----------+----+-------+-------+------+----+
```

Select the first rows from each window

```
    res5.where($"rank" === 1)
+---+----------+----+-------+-------+------+----+
|tag| timestamp|rssi|listner|rootorg|suborg|rank|
+---+----------+----+-------+-------+------+----+
|  4|1496745907| 0.6|    362|      4|     3|   1|
|  2|1496745906| 0.7|   3878|      4|     3|   1|
+---+----------+----+-------+-------+------+----+
```